# Basis of $P_2(\mathbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Check if {$1+2x+x^2, 3+x^2, x+x^2$} forms a basis of $P_2(\mathbb R)$.

My attempt:

The linear independence part:

Let $a(1+2x+x^2)+b(3+x^2)+c(x+x^2)=0$

From here I get:

$a+3b=0,
2a+c=0,
a+b+c=0$

Solving which gives me $a=b=c=0$

Question, could I have used determinant of matrix to prove linear independence here too?

The spanning part:

Let $ax^2+bx+c=\alpha_1(1+2x+x^2)+\alpha_2(3+x^2)+\alpha_3(x+x^2)$

So, equating coefficients and getting them in terms of $\alpha_1$, I get:

$\alpha_1 +\dfrac{c-\alpha_1}{3}+b-2\alpha_1=a$

from which I get the values of $\alpha$s, is this enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You proved that the set $(1+2x+x^2, 3+x^2, x+x^2)$ contains $3$ linearly independent vectors (polynomials) and since $\dim P_2(\Bbb R)=3$ then this set is a basis for $P_2(\Bbb R)$.

Notice also that you can use the determinant: the coordinates of these polynomials relative to the standard basis $(1,x,x^2)$ are respectively:

$$(1,2,1)^T\quad;\quad(3,0,1)^T\quad;\quad(0,1,1)^T$$
and we have
$$\left|\begin{matrix}1&3&0\\2&0&1\\1&1&1\end{matrix}\right|=\left|\begin{matrix}1&3&0\\1&-1&0\\1&1&1\end{matrix}\right|=-4\ne0$$
so we can conclude.

Comment: So if dimension of a vector space is N and I can show that N vectors are independent, then I can claim that it's a basis? No need to prove the span part??

Comment: Yes no need to prove the span part.

Comment: By the invertible matrix theorem, with respect to the dimension, if the associated matrix as described above is regular (det = nonzero) it covers everything

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could have used a determinant. After all, the coefficients of the three polynomial terms would form the 3 columns of this 3 by 3 matrix.
With the TI it follows that the determinant is nonzero, so a basis is satisfied in your case